# Gdebi не хочет ничего устанавливать

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

Когда я запускаю deb-пакет через браузер, стандартный файловый менеджер или командой xdg-open, gdebi выдаёт ошибку: `Refusing to render service to dead parents`. Но при открытии deb-файла из double commander всё устанавливается без проблем! Я конечно понимаю, что можно устанавливать пакеты и без gdebi, через apt, но мне хотелось бы иметь возможность делать это одним кликом. Система - Xubuntu 17.10. (На 16.04 этого бага вроде не было). Вот ещё [видео с демонстрацией](https://youtu.be/KEMYiKqCQvk). Если тоже не знаете что с этим делать, то может подскажите достойную альтернативу gdebi?

Comment: Не знаю попадалось ли, ну оставлю [тут](https://kubuntu.ru/node/3454), может поможет. Проблема была у человека та же.

Comment: @VladSpirin Спасибо. Попробовал переустановить, не помогло.

Comment: Если ответ не найдется, напишите [вот сюда](https://compizomania.blogspot.com/). Ребятки толковые там, мне частенько помогали советом.

Comment: Тот же баг на XUbuntu 18.04.

Comment: @val я сейчас уже не пользуюсь Убунтой, перешёл на Арч, так что перепроверить свою теорию не могу, но скорее всего проблема в том, что Убунту и все производные тесно интегрировали в себя gnome-software, через него теперь должны открываться deb-пакеты, а gdebi видимо где-то конфликтует и больше не актуален.

Comment: @beast winterwolf  сомнительно. При запуске `gdebi-gtk пакет` (в терминале) всё гладко. А при `xdg-open пакет` начинаются проблемы.

Comment: @val попробуйте `gnome-software пакет`

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf этот метод работает, но интересует именно gdebi-gtk.

Comment: @val вот я и говорю, что разработчики убунты его похоже сломали. они же делают gnome-software универсальным менеджером, потому что убунта теперь официально поддерживает не только deb пакеты, но также всякие flatpak и snap.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Очень оригинально сломать надо, из консоли пускать - всё ок, а через xdg-open - проблемы. К тому же, synaptic пашет вовсю. И проблема и тут, и у меня на Xubuntu.

Comment: ВАЖНО: та же проблема с любым pkexec окном без родителя. Пример: ukuu по таймеру не открывает диалог pkexec, а из окна управления своего - без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина заключалась в том, что из последних версий убунты был выпилен gksu и все остальные гуишные утилиты для получения прав рута. Теперь гуишный запрос пароля появляется от обычного sudo (например, по той же причине теперь не запускается system-config-samba). Нужно просто заменить **gksu** и **gksudo** в лаунчерах на **sudo** и всё будет работать как раньше. Для этого скопируйте оригинальный файл из `/usr/share/applications` в `~/.local/share/applications` и в копии внесите изменения, чтобы они не пропали после обновления системы.

В xfce всё делается ещё проще - правый клик по программе в меню приложений > Edit Application и дальше вписываете sudo:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя, если честно, я не уверен что этот вариант универсален, потому что у меня через **visudo** установлен беспарольный доступ, но по идее всё должно работать и с паролем.

Есть ещё один вариант из [этой статьи](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/). Тут предлагают запускать программы по специальной ссылке **admin://**, но лично у меня этот вариант почему-то не сработал, да и не нужен он, раз первый работает.